# UITableView embedded in UIPageViewController (ScrollStyle) cannot be tapped - didSelectRowAtIndexPath not fired

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

My architecture of viewcontrollers are:

```
    mainViewController(full-screen)
             |
             V
   pageViewController(part-of-screen)
         |             |
         V             V
tableViewController1 tableViewController2
```

Unlike most of existing posts, the UIPageViewController is set to style: **UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll**, which means that pageVC.gestureRecognizers is empty, and I can NOT find the tapGuesture to disable.

I've searched the site for a whole afternoon, and find NO solution (most answers are related to the pageCurlStyle). What I've tried includes:

1. setting the tableViewController.view's delegate to mainViewController, useless
2. implement gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch, not even called
3. pageVC.gestureRecognizers is empty

I haven't tried to do UITouch level things, that will be kind of dirty, and would be the last step to try.

My code is attached below, some explanations:

1. UIPageViewController* pageVC is a data member of mainViewController)
2. listVCs contains the UITableViewControllers

the code:

```
// 3. create page view controller
pageVC = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll          navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
pageVC.dataSource = self;
pageVC.delegate = self;
pageVC.doubleSided = NO;
pageVC.view.frame = _viewLayoutRef.frame;

// 3.1 set the VCs into pageVC
NSArray* aVC = @[[listVCs objectAtIndex:0]];
[pageVC setViewControllers:aVC direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO     completion:nil];

// 3.2 hook page view controller
[self addChildViewController:pageVC];
[self.view addSubview:pageVC.view];
[pageVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Can you try UITableView instead of UITableView Controller because It is working for me.

Comment: @jailani thanks for your comment. But UIPageViewController is a controller container, which manages UIViewControllers rather than UIView itself. I'm not sure how to add UITableView to UIPageViewController without UITableViewController...

Comment: From your view hierarchy...Your are feeding the view controllers(UITableViewcontroller) to uipageview controller right...Instead of UITableViewController you can create uiviewcontroller in which you can add UITableview

Comment: @jailani It's amazing, you are amazing! It works, how do you find that?... I had thought that UIViewController + UITableView == UITableViewController, but it turns out that they are so different. Thanks! BUT one remaining question: why this works? It's so magic...

Comment: I thought you didn't have .h .m files for your uitableview controller so only I suggest this way.

Comment: @jailani yes, accepted. But to answer your previous comment, I did have .h/.m files connected to the UITableViewController. When modified to UIViewController + UITableView, these 2 files changes very little (base class changed, and an IBOutlet for the embedded UITableView)

Comment: Have you set cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO any where in the code or disable uitableview userinteraction disabled in IB?

Comment: From your first point **setting the tableViewController.view's delegate to mainViewController**. you might be set your tableview delegate as wrong. Where did you implement **didSelectRow** you should do it in your table view controller probabily

Comment: @jailani the 3 solutions listed in my question are the ones I found in other posts of similar questions. I listed them so that the reader may know what I've tried before asking the question, especially for those who may have the same issue as me (there are some similar questions in stackoverflow without a final solution). And the 2 scenarios you mentioned certainly not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your view hierarchy...Your are feeding the view controllers(`UITableViewcontroller`) to `UIPageViewController` right? Instead of `UITableViewController` you can create `UIViewController` in which you can add `UITableview`.

Comment: How is this going to work..?!?! I have the same exact problem and I have viewControllers with UICollectionView inside them, but am finding problems with selections there too..!

Comment: Could you explain your problem?