# UITableView in UIPageViewController not call method didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

`containerViewController
             |
             V
      pageViewController
         |                 |
         V                 V
ViewController1    ViewController2
                           |
                           V
                       tableView (property of ViewController2)`

Hello,

I have a pageViewController with two UIViewControllers. One of them contain a tableView.
When my tableView was created in this pageViewController, the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath was never been fired. But, I can handle the "touch event" in my cell.

Look the following code:

```c
// Init pageViewController
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

self.pageController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

CGRect pageFrame = self.view.bounds;
pageFrame.origin.y = TOP_BAR_HEIGHT;
self.pageController.view.frame = pageFrame;

// Set pageviewControllers with my array of controllers (with ViewController1 and ViewController2)
[self.pageController setViewControllers:@[self.subViewControllers[0]]
                              direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                               animated:NO
                             completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageController.view];
[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

But, the things which is very strange is : when I drag on the cell with my finger, and I remove my finger, the method didSelect was fired, whereas a simple touch doesn't work...

I have already search on Stackoverflow, I've only find this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508369/uitableview-embedded-in-uipageviewcontroller-scrollstyle-cannot-be-tapped-di).

He fix his problem with an embedded tableView in a UIViewController, but I've already implemented my code like that...

EDIT: I have put the code on Github.
[source code](https://github.com/Geoffrey-T/sample-table-bug)

Comment: What object is the delegate and data source of the table view?

Comment: the delegate is ViewController2, the same thing for the datasource. But It's not a problem with the tableView directly (It work very well in an other context)

Comment: did you maybe implement didDEselect method? I had that once and searched for hours.

Comment: DidDeselect wasn't implemented... But the tableView works very well when I put it in an other controller (The tableView was use in different place in the app)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the problem...
There was a UITapGestureRecognizer on the container view. That is the bug.
Thx all.

Comment: I too am facing the same issue. Can you please shed some light on what's the issue with UITapGestureRecognizer and how you fixed it?